# Matching System

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently building a Matching System. That means I need to identify the user-dependent matches with a query. Example:

1. User X wants Product A and has Product B in return
2. User Y wants Product B and has Product A in return

=> so this would be a possible match and User X has a Product which User Y wants and contrariwise.

Now I am thinking of how to structure the database tables and how a possible select query could look like:

```
tbl_offers

offer_ID | user_ID | want_ID  | has_ID
```

And then to get the matches I would have to compare column want_ID against column has_ID, like that:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_offers WHERE user_ID = 1 AND want_ID = has_ID';
```

I do not know if this pattern is the best solution for my case, specifically if there would be performance issues when the records increase. Can you please give me a feedback if the above would work?

Thanks!

Comment: you sure about `WHERE user_ID = "1"`? double-quotes? (I'm not sure since in most sqls `1`would be a column-name then. You'd have to write  `WHERE user_ID = '1'` and escape this.) when it's an int-column (what I guess) you should just write `WHERE user_ID = 1`

Comment: This looks like a poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry you got a suggestion for another design :) ?

Comment: Well, maybe offers(offer_id*,user_id); wants(want_id*,user_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it well, you need to join your table to itself like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl_offers AS A
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_offers AS B
        ON A.want_ID = B.has_ID AND A.has_ID = B.want_ID
```

Comment: Surely you may get duplicates here as one person's want_id may be many persons has_id

Comment: That's fine, I want to show all matches to the user. In order to achieve that I just would have to add a where clause to your suggested query? Like `WHERE user_ID = 1` ?

Comment: I think: `A.user_ID = 1 or B.user_ID = 1`